# vlc and matroska format

Tags: vlc

I have two players installed on Slackware - KPlayer and Vlc. The first one always play matroska format right, but vlc has some problems.Every few minutes there is a lag, white screen and sound crash.

Parameters of video:

```
ffprobe version 2.6.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --docdir=/usr/doc/ffmpeg-2.6.3/html --mandir=/usr/man --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-libcdio --enable-libssh --enable-libcaca --enable-libsmbclient --enable-opengl --arch=x86_64
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x2057440] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'THE_THIN_RED_LINE_1998(Leon 345).mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.2.3 + libmatroska v1.3.0
    creation_time   : 2013-06-25 13:56:14
  Duration: 02:50:37.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15478 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Rip  by Leon 345 encoding  2 pass
    Stream #0:1(pol): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : AC3  5.1  Lektor  PL
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : AC3  5.1  Orginal
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : DTS-HD MA  5.1
    Stream #0:4(pol): Subtitle: subrip
    Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
    Stream #0:6: Subtitle: subrip (default) (forced)
```